# Array Funkiness in Java when passed to function

Tags: java, arrays

When I pass an array as function parameter in Java, say:

```
public static void main(String... args){
   int[] in=new int[]{57,40...23};
   int[] post=new int[]{50,18...0};//arrays abbreviated for expediency
   treeNode tree=buildTree(in, post);
   print(tree);
}

public static treeNode buildTree(int[] in, int[] post)
{   
   int root_data= post[(post.length)-1];
   int root_index=search(root_data, in);
   treeNode root=new treeNode(root_data);
   root.setLeft(buildTree(subArray(in, 0, root_index),subArray(post, 0, root_index)));
   root.setRight(buildTree(subArray(in,root_index+1, in.length),     
                  subArray(post,root_index, post.length-1)));
   return root;
}

public static int[] subArray(int[] array, int start, int end)
{
    int[] result=new int[end-start];
    for(int i=0; i<end-start;i++)
    {
        result[i]=array[start+i];
    }
    return result;
}

public static int search(int key, int[] array)
{
  for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
      if(array[i]==key)
          return key;
  }
  return array.length;
}
```

I get an `arrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception. Through the debugger I discovered that mysteriously the arrays became length 0. Why is this?

Comment: Where in your code are you getting the IndexOutOfBounds error?

Answer (score 1):

In your `search()` method you probably want to return `i` instead of `key`. Since you later use `root_index` variable (that you found with this function) as array index, that's where you might have troubles (`arrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception thrown). Even if `root_index` is within the range of array indices, its value is still wrong - to be exact, it's `0` in your example, and `subArray()` method returns empty array.

You might want to consider using standard tools instead of your own methods:

- `Arrays.sort()` followed by `Arrays.binarySearch()` to search: even though asymptotically it's worse than your simple search - O(n*lon(n)) to sort plus O(log(n)) to binary search vs. O(n) in your case - considering you probably have small arrays this is still reasonable, but you get the guaranteed correctness of the algorithm
- `Arrays.copyOfRange()` to copy range of array

Also, I don't see any definition of the `treeNode` class, but I guess you just omitted it in your posted code piece for the sake brevity.

A quick note on the style too: in Java, variables and methods are called using camelCase (so you might want to rename `root_index` into `rootIndex` and so on) and classes begin with the upper-case letter (so `treeNode` would better be named `TreeNode`). It will make your code more (intuitively) understandable to other people when they read it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorting the array may be a bad idea, since my program is building a binary tree, given the in-order and post-order of elements. I fixed the bug in my linear search but the array passed still has length 0. Any idea why?

Comment: You have 3 methods in which you pass arrays: buildTree(), subArray() and search(). In which of them does the array passed becomes of length 0? And what happens if you add `System.out.println(arrayPassedIn.length);` (where arrayPassedIn is the name of the array argument you're passing in) at the very beginning of this method?

Comment: Resolved. Need a base case to return when the array passed in is of size 0

Comment: OK, makes sense. Congrats!